# JavaScript Combine two arrays into one object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, `slicesRank` and `slicesCount` with following structure. Each element has id and value, which is an array of 46. values is composed of date and measurement.

e.g. `sliceRank[0]`:
`{id: Catan=rank,  values(Array(46)) : {date, measurement} }`

e.g. `sliceCount[0]`:
`{id: Catan=count,  values(Array(46)) : {date, measurement} }`

What should I do if I want to combine the elements with the same prefix in id names. For example, the first element in this two arrays.

The desired sturcture would be
`{id: Catan,  values(Array(46)) : {date, count, rank} }`

I tried the following, but the `values` shows undifined.

```
    for(i=0; i<slicesRank.length; i++) {
        var newElement = {};
        newElement['id'] = slicesRank[i].id.replace('=rank', '');
        newElement['values'] = {
          date: slicesRank[i].date,
          rank: slicesRank[i].measurement,
          count: slicesCount[i].measurement
        };
        sliceNew.push(newElement);
    };
```

The structure of `slicesRank` is like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: `{id: Catan=rank,  values(Array(46)) : {date, measurement} }` is not valid syntax. It's not clear what the data structure you're working with is

Comment: @CertainPerformance  Hi, sorry to any confusion caused here. I'm new to JS. I added two screenshot trying to show the structure of `slicesRank` here, would that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample transformation that you can try:

```
const combined = slicesRank.map((rank) => {
  const id = rank.id.replace("=rank", "");
  const count = slicesCount.find(
    (count) => count.id.replace("=count", "") === id
  );
  return {
    id,
    values: rank.values.map((val, index) => ({
      date: val.date,
      rank: val.measurement,
      count: count?.values[index].measurement
    }))
  };
});
```

Here's a working example
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-lovelace-e31zj?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1):

By *slice* I think you mean `Array`.

```js
const combinedArray = sliceRank.map((sliceItem, itemIndex) => {
    return {
        id,
        values: sliceItem.values.map(({ date, measurement }, valueIndex) => ({
            date,
            count: sliceCount[itemIndex][valueIndex].measurement,
            rank: measurement,
        }))
    }
})
```

This solution returns an array of objects combined using `sliceRank` and `sliceCount`. So now each array item now contains `values` of structure `{ date, count, rank }`. `Array.map` is immutable so both slices will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
let sliceRank=[{id: "Catan=rank",  values : [{"date":"10/10/2020", "measurement":120} ]}];
let sliceCount=[{id: "Catan=count",  values :[{"date":"10/10/2020", "measurement":20} ] }];

let newData=[];

const data = sliceRank.map((slice, sliceIndex) => {
    return {
        id:slice.id.split("=")[0],
        values: slice.values.map(({ date, measurement }, valueIndex) => ({
            date,            
            rank: measurement,
            count: sliceCount[sliceIndex].values.map(r=> r.measurement)[0],
        }))
    }
})

console.log(data);
```